# Fast Graphics library which can support Animated GIFs

Tags: c++, c, graphics, imagemagick

I am using ImageMagick with *animated gifs* but it is very slow. Taking twenty seconds for a single animation. Is there an alternate C/C++ graphics library which is fast? A good result may be those libraries that can handle huge images. But do any of those support *animated* GIFs?

These are the features I am needing:

- Split animated GIF into completely rendered frames, save in any format.
- Change certain colors in these resulting images to White
- Crop out a portion of each of the resulting images.
- Recreate an animated GIF with 2 frames, from the resulting 2 images above. This GIF should be optimized. Delay on the first frame differs from delay on last frame.

It needs to be fast, much faster than either imagemagic or graphicsmagic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`giflib` [to parse the GIF format and save to] and **C++** (for the image processing). This seems the best solution for me. Also using ImageMagick's `Magick++` library could improve performance a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Try `libavcodec` and `libavformat` from the FFmpeg project or the `libav` fork thereof. These are almost surely the fastest and most flexible you'll find, but the interface complexity might be more than you were asking for.

Comment: @R I was more thinking of an 'all-in-one' solution, AFAIK FFmpeg is encoder/decoder only? does it do processing as well?

Comment: There's a filter library/framework too and you could use existing filters in it or add your own (afaik it's not hard for the calling app to add filters without making them part of the library).

Comment: @R note that the `libav.org` seems the official place for the development of `libavcodec` from now on..

Comment: Apparently there's a bitter feud between the ffmpeg.org and libav.org camps over bruised egos and the like. I know and respect several people on both sides and I'd rather not pass judgement about which to use. Honestly I wish some people would just say "I'm sorry" to each other and get back to providing the best possible AV processing tools.

Answer (score 0):

[FreeImage](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/) is similar to FFMPEG and libav, but for images. I believe it does everything you're looking for.

Comment: But it's also very slow for animated GIFs.